# What would be some earlier comments on "1+2+3+4=10"?

Tags: reference-request, ancient-india

"1+2+3+4=10" is an arithmetical triviality that is popular as an example of Pythagoreanism.  There seems to be no mention of it in ancient Greek texts prior to Speusippus (e.g. ca. 350BCE; see Zhmud's *Arithmology*), so  it seems rightly considered to be *pseudo*-pythagorean. There is however a possibility that it could have been noted and/or commented  at earlier times in some other accessible culture, e.g. Egypt or India, etc (probably not Babylon where they used hexadecimal numbers). Refs to papers or sources mentioning such early occurences would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem with seeking references to this is that the references would provide essentially no information as to when someone "first" considered adding consecutive integers. This was likely done on many occasions thousands of years earlier than 350 BC, as surely such sums sometimes occurred in financial or trading transactions, as well as just playing around with counting stones or sticks. In fact, surely sums of the first few positive integers as corresponding to the number of objects in a triangular array dates back several thousand years BEFORE writing, probably over $10,000$ years ago.

Comment: I doubt that there are any. Even [Herdmans](https://juliaherdman.com/2019/07/21/how-did-the-egyptians-influence-the-greeks/), cranky authors that "uncover" secret Egyptian numerology everywhere have to admit that "*The Pythagorean Mystery Numbers are not exactly what the Egyptians were up to*", and the "Indian roots" of the tetractys are the invention of Blavatsky of the Theosophical Society, see [Fitger, p.14](https://www.academia.edu/40271715/The_tetractys_and_the_hebdomad_Blavatskys_Sacred_Geometry_Unveiled).

Comment: @Cornifold. Thanks, I would have missed the Blavatsky connection: it is something like outfaking the fake. It seems however that Plato also has been also heading into cuckooland with his ideal ('eidetic') numbers.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro. It is not a question 'Who first' but 'Did anybody think this triviality worth noting'.

Comment: I still think various aspects of this identity would have been discovered/observed independently many times in prehistoric times from drawing triangular arrays of marks in sand/dirt or arranging objects in triangular arrays, perhaps observing that, at the 4th level, the number of marks/objects is equal to the number of fingers or perhaps otherwise trying to match the triangular numbers with numbers of things in other contexts. I think it's easy to underestimate just how many elementary observations/connections many tens of thousands of people each year can make over a period of 100,000+ years.

Comment: Personally, I do not think that it is "*pseudo*-pythagorean": various pythagorean numerological ideas are referred to by Aristotle as well as Lucian, with reference for *tetraktys* to [Philolaus](https://books.google.it/books?id=GtliSUQqeyoC&pg=PA356).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Zhmud presented evidence that most of Aristotle's account of Pythagoreans is manufactured for expository and polemic purposes. And Huffman's book you linked remarks about the Lucian's fragment that "*one would emphacize the questionable nature of most of the rest of arithmology assigned to Philolausas*" and "*in the end the testimonium must remain of uncertain authenticity*".